# Reading Session value in View MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session, model-view-controller

I have a Session in my Controller as follow

```
Session["Fulldata"] = data;
```

Which stores **data** like Name,Id,City etc;

It stores multiple rows of such data.

How how do I access or check if any row has particular Name in it, in the View?

eg :

```
@if(Session("Fulldata").has("ABC"))
{
   //Do Something
}
```

I want to check Name for each row in Session. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: What is format of data is it your custom class collection?

Comment: You need to first cast the object to the model type (e.g to `IEnumerable<yourModel>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you need to cast the `Session("Fulldata")` back to you type as session store your collection as `object` type.

```
List<CustomClass> data = (List<CustomClass>)Session("Fulldata");
```

If data is a collection you can use linq [Enumerable.Any](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534972(v=vs.100).aspx) to Search

```
@if(data.Any(d=>d.YourAttr1 == 'ABC' || d.YourAttr2 == 'ABC'))
{
   //Do Something
}
```

As a additional *note* please do not use session unnecessarily especially for big data as session will need space on your server and as user/session increase it could adversely effect the performance.

Comment: It is list. Can i do above in View?

Comment: List of strings? or list of custom type like your custom class?

Comment: List of custom class. List<MyClass>. and MyClass has properties like Name,Address etc

Comment: Then you would need to cast it to List<CustomClass>, as you can see in my answer.

Comment: Yes, you can use code blocks, see an example here, http://www.asp.net/web-pages/overview/getting-started/introducing-razor-syntax-(c)